# two methods handling Me.FormClosing; why do they fire in this specific order?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
      Handles Me.Load, Me.FormClosing
        MessageBox.Show("form_load")
End Sub


Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs) _
    Handles Me.FormClosing
    MessageBox.Show("form_closing")
End Sub
```

While closing the form I observed that the `Form1_FormClosing` method is fired first, and then `Form1_Load` second.

Why is this order chosen?  Why doesn't `Form1_Load` get fired/entered first, and then `Form1_FormClosing` second?

How does .NET choose which method to fire first, of the two that handle the same event?

Comment: be..cause form_load is fired when you load the form?

Comment: you mean to say, for that reason its firing next to 'form_closing' while closing !!??

Comment: How do you load the form?  How do you close the form?  Can you show us the code where that happens?  If you're calling `Me.Close()` if the form's `Load` event handler, this is plausible.

Comment: with just above events I created exe and loaded and closed manually. I didn't load/unload in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both method have `Handles Me.FormClosing`, so both methods are executed when the form is closed.  There's no particular orer they're executed in.

When several methods handle the same event, the event calls them in the order they asked to receive events.  The compiler has arbitrarily decided that the `Form1_FormClosing` method comes first.  Try adding this code between the the two method and see if it changes again.

```
Private Sub Aaa(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs)
    Handles Me.FormClosing
    MsgBox("Aaa")
End Sub
```

On a side note, I'm surprised your code compiles as `Form.Load` has a different signature to `Form.FormClosing`.

---

If you want code to execute in a particular order, only handle the event once and call other methods in order.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Handles Me.Load
    ReportLoad()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs)
    Handles Me.FormClosing
    ReportLoad()
    MsgBox("Form1_FormClosing")
End Sub

Private Sub ReportLoad()
    MsgBox("ReportLoad")
End Sub
```

Handling an event in a method of a different name is misleading and confusing.  I'd never have guessed that `Form1_Load` would be called by the `FormClosing` event.  If you want to handle several events, or the same event of several objects, in one method, change the method name, like `Form1_xxx` or `xxxButton_Click` so that it's clear that multiple events are being handled.

Comment: may be you are correct.. I tried with three more methods to handle the same event..every time I added a method, order changed..

Comment: To your "side note", [since VS 2008 variance in delegate (including event) signatures has been possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233060.aspx) - because any `FormClosingEventArgs` is also an `EventArgs`, it's clear that the posted `Form1_Load` method *can* accept the arguments of `FormClosing`, and nowadays the compiler understands that well enough to allow it.